# Can't update apps from Apple Configurator 2 (apps are already up to date)

Tags: macos, ios, software-update, apple-configurator

I attach an iPhone running iOS 12.2 to a mac running macOS 10.14.4 (Mojave) with 33 apps pending updates (as seen from App Store in the update tab in the iPhone). I choose the device, then "update" in Apple Configurator 2 (v. 2.9). Then I get the message "No updates are available. The installed iOS and apps are already up to date." and no apps get updated.

Is there a way to make Apple Configurator 2 recognize the pending updates?

Comment: I'm seeing the same problem. Did you ever find a way to resolve this?

Comment: @JamesParker Still same issue on iOS 13.3.1, macOS 10.14.6 and Apple Configurator 2 (2.11.1)

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem recently in macOS 10.15 (Catalina) with an iPhone 11 Pro Max.

The App Store app on the iPhone showed 19 updates available via a red badge on the app icon as well as inside of the app. Meanwhile, the Apple Configurator app on the Mac claimed no updates were available.

[image: App Store: app badge]

[image: App Store: updates list]

Restarting the iPhone didn't change anything as far as I could tell.

But after restarting the **Mac** and launching Apple Configurator again, it now showed **34 updates available**, which still doesn't match what is shown on the iPhone, but I guess it's better than zero!

[image: Apple Configurator: updates]

Clicking the Update button in Configurator resulted in the apps being downloaded and updated. By the time the update process finished, **32** updates were downloaded, and I received an "unknown error" on the last two.

Apple Configurator's handling of app updates seems to be quite buggy.